# How can i verify that the url is correct

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click a link and make sure the link that opens is correct.
When I run the test, after clicking the link, it opens in a new tab.
The new tab is in focus but the comparison is still in the previous tab.
Someone?

This is my code:

```
HomePage homepage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
homepage.openHomePage();
homepage.openSignUpPage();
SignUpPage signUpPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SignUpPage.class);
signUpPage.checkTermsOfServiceURL();
driver.findElement(link_terms_of_services).click();    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("https://www.atlassian.com/legal/cloud-terms-of-service"));
```

This is the result:

waiting for url to be "https://www.atlassian.com/legal/cloud-terms-of-service". Current url: "https://trello.com/signup"

Comment: `assertEquals(getTextofURL(), expectedURL);` may be this is what suffice your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the driver to the new tab, like so:

```
const windowHandles = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
await driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles[1]);
```

Then you can wait for the URL in that tab, like so:

```
await driver.wait(async () => {
    const currentURL = await driver.getCurrentUrl();
    return currentURL === url;
}, timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly states that the driver's current focus is on the previous window and not the new window that opened. New window may be visible to you but this does not mean that the driver is also focused on the same.
Use the following code after clicking on terms of service:

```
String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();

Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();       
Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();              
        while(i1.hasNext())         
        {       
            String ChildWindow=i1.next();       

            if(!MainWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))           
            {           

                    // Switching to Child window
                    driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);
                  // do your stuff
            }
```

***You can switch back to your parent window by:***

```
            driver.switchTo().window(MainWindow);
```